# YQL: data>RSS feed - with images only

Tags: sql, yql

I'm using this to retrieve RSS news feeds from Yahoo (JSON):

```
select * from xml where url in(  
  'http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/us',  
  'http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/world'  
)
```

Is it possible to limit returned items to only those with image content? Something like:

> ... WHERE content.type == 'image/jpeg'

Or maybe "SORT BY .. something" - so it returns items with images 1st?

Console is here: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console

Thank you.

Comment: Nvm. Answering my own question: select * from xml where url='http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories' and channel.item.content.type = 'image/jpeg' :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from xml where url in(  
  'http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/us',  
  'http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/world'  
) and itemPath="//item" and content.type = 'image/jpeg'
```